# Can't select an image even when it's not locked and it is in front

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This happens in Adobe Illustrator CC. 
When I tried to select an object, it tends to select the thing behind it. The object is not locked and is in the front of the same layer.
I have took a video showing this issue. https://youtu.be/cdiBTXwe-CM
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Illustrator? I find that it usually fixes these weird bugs.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried, but it doesn't work as though it is not a bug.

Comment: Try ctl+ y, zoom in real close to make sure your not actually clicking trough the object? My thinking is the objects are not actually solid? Hard to tell in the vid.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which we noticed on this.

1. You can drag and select that specific image.
2. You can increase the size of the image and then it will work fine.
3. If you image trace it, then it will also work fine.
4. You can drag and move it, if you select the top centre point of bounding box.

I think it is due to colour coding, not a proper solution but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Pick the selection tool and then go to preferences, make sure they match this:

[image]

Comment: Specifically? I doubt most of those settings would be causing problems

Comment: My settings *don't* match those.